# Adding further array data to the array

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, qtablewidget

I have below code, where data in variables is changed with iterable loop for.

for i in range(self.tableWidget_16.rowCount()):

```
s = int(self.tableWidget_16.text()) #this data is taken from table , example view from print it: 1042
b = int(self.tableWidget_15.text()) #this data is taken from table , example view from print it: 0
c = int(self.tableWidget_14.text()) #this data is taken from table , example view from print it: 424

array = [[s,b,c]]
```

'''
I have result like this:
line 1[1042,0,424]
line 2[2425,0,135]

I want like this:
line 1[[1042,0,424],[2425,0,135],[...,...,...],...]

How can I do this?

Comment: create an empty array outside the loop and `.append()` to it your `[s,b,c]`

Comment: This work perfect, thank you!